# How to send attachment in email from GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Input required and not supplied: `username`.

I already configured the secrets but even so the error persists.

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Newman Tests by Postman.

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  schedule:
  - cron: '5 17 * * MON-FRI'
  
  workflow_dispatch:
permissions: write-all

jobs:
  report-automated-api:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
        # 1 - Step - Install dependences.
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm install -g newman | 
             npm install -g allure-commandline --save-dev |
             npm install -g newman-reporter-allure 

      # 2 -Step - Run the POSTMAN collection
      - name: Step 2 - Run POSTMAN collection
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
             newman run florida_release_notes.postman_collection.json -e Env-1fpay-test.postman_environment.json -r allure

      - name: mostra as pastas
        run: dir
      - name:  Step 3 - Collect Allure files and generate allure-report folder
        run: |
          allure generate ./allure-results -o allure-report/
          
      - name:  Step 4 - Publishing Allure artifact to GitHub Actions
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: allure-report
          path: allure-report
    
      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_branch: gh-pages  # default: gh-pages
          publish_dir: allure-report
          destination_dir: allure-report
          
      - name: Send email
        uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v2
        with:
         server_address: smtp.gmail.com
         server_port: 587
         username: ${{secrets.USER}}
         password: ${{secrets.PASS}}
         subject: Teste de envio de e-mail
         body: |
          Olá,
          https://staulik.github.io/aut-api-pefisa/allure-report/#
          Atenciosamente,
          Seu nome
         to: staulik10@gmail.com
```

Comment: Which step is that error coming from? Please include that in your question. Apparently, only `username` in your workflow is the last step i.e. send email. Have you verified that `secrets.USER` has properly been configured e.g. by printing it in a separate step?